# Problem with iOS Dev: Date Formatting

Tags: objective-c, ios, date-format

I have this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:kCFDateFormatterNoStyle];

[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

NSString *dateAdded = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

[t appendFormat:@" (added at %@)", dateAdded];
```

*t* is a **NSMutableArray**.

I don't know what's wrong with it but the result is *dateAdded* turned out to be a **empty** string. If I replace the last line with

```
[t appendFormat:@" (added at %@)", [NSDate date]];
```

everything goes just fine, except date is output in raw form.

But what's wrong with my formatting?

Comment: how can you append format to nsmutablearray? o0

Comment: I assume you meant to say that t is a NSMutableString and not a NSMutableArray?

Comment: You've set the time style to NoStyle but you haven't set the date style.  Try explicitly setting the date style to whatever you want it to be.  If that's not it, go in with the debugger and check everything (put the anonymous variables [NSDate date] and [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] into vars and check them too).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I missed NSMutableArray for NSMutableString.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the date style to something other than kCFDateFormatterNoStyle.

Comment: I tried more than that. I comment-cancelled line 2 & 3, but it was still the same -- empty string.

Comment: Your code shows that you set the time style but not the date style. One of them should be set to a value like kCFDateFormatterShortStyle. Commenting out your existing lines won't help - You need to add a line.

Comment: YES!! You are RIGHT. If I do not explicitly tell the formatter what to do, it might give nothing to me. Thanks a lot!